# How to set counter in mysql?

Tags: mysql, web-applications

I have been creating web-application, but I wanted to create counter to keep track of pages viewed. So, I want to create a counter in mysql.

Scenario is something like this..

if row isn't created,
create row

if row is created,
set the counter.

Is this possible?

Or should I run two queries to do so.

query 1: run query to select table that doesn't exist. if it returns null,
it doesn't have data entry.

query 2: So, create entry for that, using the counter.

query 3: if data is already created, increment the counter.

But is there a way to do it in a single call to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.

So, you have a `PagesViewed` table with some sort of page identifier and a counter.  You do:

```
insert into PagesViewed(pageid, counter)
     select $pageid, 1
     on duplicate key update counter = counter + 1;
```

This requires a unique index on `pagesviewed(pageid)`.

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem. my question is

1. if entry isn't made, create entry.
2. if entry is present, update it by counter!

Comment: @Rockink . . . Hmmm.  That is *exactly* what this logic does.  Hence, it is unclear how this does not solve the problem.  I note that in your question you say "increment" but in the comment you say "update it by counter."